# accidentally modified python in linux

Tags: python, linux

I recently modified my python while working on a project linux by adding third-party module in it (I did `mv clip.py /usr/bin/python`) due to which i cannot open IDLE and cannot run  python from terminal. It broke my interpreter and gives this error `bash: /usr/bin/idle: /usr/bin/python: bad interpreter: Permission denied`

Any solution to this is very much appreciated.

When i try to reinstall the package it gives this error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Reinstallation of python is not possible, it cannot be downloaded.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Comment: Just reinstall the python package, i.e. `sudo apt-get install --reinstall python`

Comment: Also, installing third-party modules in a way that would allow this to happen sounds like a terrible terrible idea. Read up on [`virtualenv`s and `pip`](https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtualenv/).

Comment: This should not be possible unless you are root. Lesson learned: Don't operate as root.

Comment: it says  Reinsatllation of python is not possible

Answer (score 2):

In such case the best way is to reinstall python and all the modules you use (just in case).
Depend of your OS it can be with command (as `root`)

**RHEL:**

```
yum reinstall python
```

**Debian/Ubuntu:**

```
apt-get install --reinstall python
```

**SuSE:**

```
zypper in -f python
```

If you have problem install via `yum`, `apt-get`, `zypper` you can download the package and install it by hand (suppose the name of the package is python-version.deb or rpm):

**RHEL, SuSE:**

```
rpm -ivfh python-version.rpm
```

**Debian/Ubuntu:**

```
dpkg --force-all -i python-version.deb
```

After such installation you can get warnings about inconsistent package database which (IMHO) you can ignore

Comment: it says  Reinsatllation of python is not possible

Comment: DId you do it as `root`? If yes I will ad to my question answer how to install it by hand

Comment: Yes I did. I first used the command `su root` (If necessary i will also  login as root) the tried the command you suggested

Comment: The better command to become root is `su - root`. Check UNIX/Linux SE site for answer why. And please provide in your question the exact error you get when try to reinstall

Comment: I tried `dpkg --force-all -i python-2.7.0.deb` and `dpkg --force-all -i python.deb` both didn't work. It gives this error `dpkg: error: cannot access archive 'python-2.7.0.deb': No such file or directory`

Comment: Did you download the file before? And with `apt-get` install `python2.7`